# Cannot write to sd card on android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have an issue with writing to sd card on my android 4.4 device. I'm writing an application that gets path to its directory on sd card using the getExternalFilesDirs() method. But when I try to store data in the directory I get an error:

```
EACCES (Permisson denied)
```

The applications directories in Android/data/ in both internal memory and on the sd card are owned by different linux users. Any other application on my device works fine. The application works on another device with that sd card.

Comment: I searched for "EACCES access denied android" and got this link where it mentions that KitKat added restrictions so that only system processes can write to all directories.  User processes can only write to specific directories:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86251/receiving-an-eaccess-permission-denied-error-when-copying-files-to-extsdcard

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: also, if you are targeting api level 23+, you need to manually request permission from the user. Check this link:https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: And you don't need that permission to write to the application-specific directory. The problem is that the directory on sd card is being created by another user (like it's being created from another application)

Comment: I also have problems and I use android 5. Only my file manager and winrar can write to my sdcard. I added both permissions mentioned here. but I cant write, only read the sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have missplaced this line. 
Double check this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

where you have put this line?

this line should be outside of `<application/>` scope

like this

```
<manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        ...
        <application>
            ...
            <activity> 
                ...
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

For getExternalFilesDirs to return the path of the sdcard, the OEM must have set the SECONDARY_STORAGE environment variable in the device specific init.rc file as mentioned here: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example.html

Look at the source of getExternalFilesDirs here: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1039

The value is obtained from Environment.buildExternalStorageAppFilesDirs. Look at that source here: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Environment.java#206

The value is dependent on mExternalDirsForApp, which in turn is populated by reading the contents of SECONDARY_STORAGE variable: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Environment.java#136

As you can see, if the SECONDARY_STORAGE variable is not set, the sdcard path will not be returned. You can cross-check this by going to adb shell and looking at the output of echo $SECONDARY_STORAGE

Comment: No, I have not. The application works fine on other devices.

Comment: if the SECONDARY_STORAGE variable is not set, we cannot access the external sd card

Comment: SECONDARY_STORAGE is set. And getExternalFilesDirs returns the path to the aplication directory on sd card.

Answer (score 0):

use **getExternalFilesDir()**

It returns the path to files folder inside Android/data/data/your_package/ on your secondary storage SD card. It is used to store any required files for your app (e.g. images downloaded from web or cache files). Once the app is uninstalled, any data stored in this folder is gone too.

This is where you can write file in secondary storage ie(your micro sdcard)

if you want to write outside or the root of the secondary storage you have to use **Storage access framework** .